# wild card url to point to root Folderd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need all the not found url to point to root folder.

for example `http://dom.com/askjdhakjhsd/aksjhdkasjhd.html` or `http://dom.com/asjkdkjash/` to show the content of `http://dom.com/`,,,but url should be shown as it is like `http://dom.com/askjdhakjhsd/aksjhdkasjhd.html` **not redirection**

I used below code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)(\/?)$ / [QSA,NC,L]
```

its working fine , But     `<link href="/css/hello.css" rel="stylesheet">` is pointing to `http://dom.com/askjdhakjhsd/css/hello.css` ... how to properly show content of root folder but url should be `http://dom.com/askjdhakjhsd/aksjhdkasjhd.html` .

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ErrorDocument` line. Add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

This will forward even 404 (not found) error to your home page while keeping the URL same in browser.